# Pandas DataFrame groupby columns to dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe named df looks like

`Dig  CUI  importance
 2240 a123 0.28912
 2240 b123 0.39021
 2230 x133 0.12923
 3330 cak2 0.12903
 3330 xa45 0.21093
 3330 2429 0.21893`

To the above dataframe I am running it through the following code,

`df = (df.groupby('dig').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['cui'],x['importance']))).to_dict())`

I am getting an output as

`{2240:{a123:0.28912, b123:0.39021},2230:{x133:0.12923},3330:{cak2: 0.12903, xa45:0.21093, 2429:0.21893}}`

But I need columns in my output dictionary.I need suggestions

the output should be like

`{2240:[{cui:a123, importance:0.28912},{cui:b123, importance:0.39021}],2230:[{cui:x133, importance:0.12923},3330:[{cui:cak2, importance:0.12903},{cui:xa45, importance:0.21093},{cui:2429, importance:0.21893}]]}`

Suggest me ways to do it.

Comment: Please format your code so that it's readable.

Comment: Hi @Nimmala and welcome to Stackoverflow, while you may catch some flack for your (terribly) unformatted post, let me link you to a page that explains formatting in more detail. Proper formatting helps other users more quickly give you the best answers. Checkout the [Markdown and Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help

Comment: Formated my code, Please take a look @AndreyPortnoy. Thanks you all for immediate response.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to groupby on Dig, like you're doing, but call `to_dict('records')` inside the apply:

```
In [103]: df.groupby("Dig").apply(lambda x: x.drop("Dig", 1).to_dict('records')).to_dict()
Out[103]: 
{2230: [{'CUI': 'x133', 'importance': 0.12922999999999998}],
 2240: [{'CUI': 'a123', 'importance': 0.28912},
  {'CUI': 'b123', 'importance': 0.39021}],
 3330: [{'CUI': 'cak2', 'importance': 0.12903},
  {'CUI': 'xa45', 'importance': 0.21093},
  {'CUI': '2429', 'importance': 0.21893}]}
```